# Boostrap 3 col boxes overlapping content?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

For some strange reason my content is overlapping too far across despite me declaring that it should be using  col-md-3 4 times?

Here is my code:

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3">

            <p>gjhdgjkhgkjhdgjkhgjkhsdglkjhsgkjhlkjhkjdfghjdkghfdkjghjkghsjkh</p>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">

            <p>gjhdgjkhgkjhdgjkhgjkhsdglkjhsgkjhlkjhkjdfghjdkghfdkjghjkghsjkh</p>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">

            <p>gjhdgjkhgkjhdgjkhgjkhsdglkjhsgkjhlkjhkjdfghjdkghfdkjghjkghsjkh</p>

        </div>

        <div class="col-md-3">

            <p>gjhdgjkhgkjhdgjkhgjkhsdglkjhsgkjhlkjhkjdfghjdkghfdkjghjkghsjkh</p>

        </div>                


    </div>  

</div>
```

And here is a pic:

[image: Bootstrap 3]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because you have no space in your "words".
If you want to break a word when the content area runs out of space you can use css:

```
word-break = "break-all";
```

I would not recommend it though.

You can also use:

```
overflow: hidden;
```

Anyways, I think you might just not have a problem if you just use regular text.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/s5Jaj/)

Comment: I appreciate the issue and I understand that is the problem but I thought that Bootstrap handled this automatically? Normal text behaves the same.

Comment: You mean that even with regular words you have this problem?

Comment: I see what you mean - I put a space into the string of characters and it has broken the line down into the columns - that is interesting.

Answer (score 1):

You would  be fine using css:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```